# IEEE 754 Float debug - from memory little endian to the actual floating number

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, ieee-754

I am testing IEEE 754 floating format with VS2008 using the example below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float i = 0.15625;
}
```

I put &i to the VS2008 watch and I see the address is 0x0012FF60 and I can see address's content is 00 00 20 3e from Memory debug window, see below:

> 0x0012FF60  00 00 20 3e cc cc cc cc

BTW I have the basic knowledge of IEEE754 floating format and I know IEEE 754 floating format consist of three fields: sign bit, exponent, and fraction. The fraction is the significand  without its most significant bit.

But how did I calcuate exactly from little endian 00 00 20 3e to 0.15625 ?

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs, it's really clear now, up tick for everyone !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing out something broken. We only need 32 bits, which are:

```
00 00 20 3E
```

Your variable in binary:

```
00000000 00000000 00100000 00111110
```

Logical value accounting for little endian:

```
00111110 00100000 00000000 00000000
```

According to IEEE:

```
0 01111100 01000000000000000000000
S E - 127  M - 1
```

So now it's clear:

- the sign is +1 (`S = 0`)
- the exponent is 124 - 127 = -3
- the mantissaa is 1.01b, which is 5/4

So the value is 5/4 / 8 = 5/32 = 0.15625.

Comment: And that's not a print, it's what I copied from VS2008 memory debug window

Answer (score 6):

Memory layout of a 32bit float ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision ) on  a big endian machine.

[image]

A little endian machine (eg. x86) simply swaps pairs of bytes, the 'cc' are unused bits of memory to make the 32bit float upto a 64bit value being displayed by the debugger

edit:
Remember the exponent is signed (twos complement) and since 0.15625 is less than 1 the exponent is negative)

value = sign * 2^exp * mantissa.

0x3e = 0011 1110
0x20 = 0010 0000

Because of the sign bit we have to shuffle these along one so
exponent = 0111 1100 = -3
mantissa = 0100 0000 = 1 + 0.25  ( the one before the first place is assumed)

ie  0.15625 = +1 * 2^(-3) * 1.25

Comment: what's the bit order in this image ? It's read 7C 40, even in reverse order(assume it's big endian?), it's 02 3e, instead of 20 3e. Am I missing something obvious here ?

Comment: I'm suspicious about "swaps pairs of bytes", which isn't what's happening on the OP's machine.

Comment: Also, the exponent isn't "signed", it's "biased"!

Comment: The exponent is signed in math, it's simply biased in it's storage

Answer (score 1):

Your value is hex 0x3E200000 or

```
0011 1110 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

or rearranged:

```
s ----e--- ----------m------------
0 01111100 01000000000000000000000

sign_bit    = 0 (i.e. positive)
exponent    = 0x7C = 124 ---> subtract 127 to get -3
significand = 1 + 0.0100... = 1.0100... = 1*2^0 + 0*2^-1 + 1*2^-2 = 1.25

significand * 2^exponent = 1.25 * 2^-3 = 1.25 * 0.125 = 0.15625
```

Comment: Why `-4`? Why is the sign "zero"?

Comment: The sign ***bit*** is zero. -4 was a typo and corrected. Renamed sign to sign_bit.

Answer (score 1):

The basic format of an IEEE floating point is based on a four byte 
value, and it is simpler to analyse if you display it as such.  In that
case, the top bit is the exponent, the next 8 the exponent (in excess
127), and the rest the mantissa.  The simplest way to explain it is
probably to show the C++ code which would access the separate fields:

```
double d;
// ...
uint32_t const* p = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t const*>( &d );
bool isNegative = (*p & 0x80000000) != 0;
int exp = ((*p & 0x78000000) >> 23) - 127;
int mantissa = (*p & 0x07FFFFFF) | 0x08000000 ;
```

The mantissa should have an implicit decimal place just above the 24
bits (But I don't know how to represent this as an integer:-)).

If all you have is a sequence of bytes, you have to assemble them,
according to the byte order, and then apply the above.

Edited: the constant values have been corrected, following up on Rudy Velthuis' pointing out my error.

Comment: That is `int exp = ((*p & 0x78000000) >> 23) - 127;` and the same for isNegative.

Comment: @Rudy Yes.  I don't know what I was thinking of.  I did work a lot on 16 bit machines in the distant past, but I've never seen a 16 bit floating point format:-)  I'll edit it (all of the hex values are affected)---thanks for the correction.